# How do I change the layout along with an animation in Java FX?

Tags: animation, layout, javafx

I want a menu on the left side of my application to slide in to the frame when a user selects a toggle-button and out again when the toggled button is not selected.

I achieved everything I wanted but I got the problem that the layout doesn't change with the animation.

When the menu is out of the frame (you can't see it) the layout is like it is in the frame.

This is the initialization of my menu:

```
modulesBar = new ModulesBar();
modulesBar.setTranslateX(-250);
GridPane.setMargin(modulesBar, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 5));
GridPane.setRowSpan(modulesBar, GridPane.REMAINING);
root.add(modulesBar, 0, 1);
```

This is the switch-method:

```
Timeline modulesBarAnimation = new Timeline();

if (mainBar.getModulesButton().isSelected()) {
    modulesBarAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250), new KeyValue(modulesBar.translateXProperty(), 0)));
} else {
    modulesBarAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250), new KeyValue(modulesBar.translateXProperty(), -250)));
}
modulesBarAnimation.playFromStart();
```

I also tried using `setLayoutX()` but that doesn't move the menu out of the frame...

How do I get the layout to change with the translation? Best would be a smooth change coupled with the animation.

Comment: Check out jewelsea's example: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374

Answer (score 1):

Any transforms on a `Node` are not taken into account in the layout. (This is deliberate; among other things it allows you to modify the position of a `Node` relative to its usual layout position.) Your animation works by modifying the standard translate transform; hence this will not alter the layout.

In order to get the effect you want, you need the animation to modify a property that is used in computing the layout. For example, since you seem to be using a `GridPane`, you could apply `ColumnConstraints` to the `GridPane` and modify the `prefWidth` of one of the columns.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class AnimatingGridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane root = new GridPane();

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setPrefWidth(100);

        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();

        root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);

        ObservableBooleanValue expanded = leftCol.prefWidthProperty().greaterThan(0);

        Button expandButton = new Button("");
        expandButton.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.when(expanded).then("Hide options").otherwise("Show options"));

        expandButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            KeyFrame start ;
            KeyFrame end ;

            if (expanded.get()) {
                start = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(leftCol.prefWidthProperty(), 100));
                end = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250), new KeyValue(leftCol.prefWidthProperty(), 0));
            } else {
                start = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(leftCol.prefWidthProperty(), 0));
                end = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(250) ,new KeyValue(leftCol.prefWidthProperty(), 100));                    
            }

            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(start, end);

            timeline.play();
        });

        Node content = createContent();

        root.setVgap(5);
        root.add(content, 1, 0);

        Region optionsPane = createOptionsPane();

        root.add(optionsPane, 0, 0);

        optionsPane.visibleProperty().bind(expanded);

        optionsPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        GridPane.setHalignment(expandButton, HPos.CENTER);
        root.add(expandButton, 1, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private GridPane createContent() {
        GridPane contentPane = new GridPane();

        contentPane.setHgap(5);
        contentPane.setVgap(5);

        contentPane.addRow(0, new Label("First Name:"),  new TextField());
        contentPane.addRow(1, new Label("Last Name:"),  new TextField());
        contentPane.addRow(2, new Label("Email:"),  new TextField());

        ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        leftCol.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);
        leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);

        ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
        rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        rightCol.setFillWidth(true);

        contentPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);
        return contentPane;
    }

    private Region createOptionsPane() {
        VBox optionsPane = new VBox(10, 
                createLabel("New"),
                createLabel("Open"),
                createLabel("Edit"),
                createLabel("Delete")
            );
        return optionsPane;
    }

    private Label createLabel(String text) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setEllipsisString("");
        return label ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Translations do not affect the layout, you have to use methods that influence the layout.

(In this case) Changing the width of the `modulesBar` with `setPrefWidth(...)` affects the layout and achieves the desired result.

The code for the initialization of the menu is as follows:

```
modulesBar = new ModulesBar();
modulesBar.setPrefWidth(0);
modulesBar.setMinWidth(0);
modulesBar.setTranslateX(-200);
GridPane.setMargin(modulesBar, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 5));
root.add(modulesBar, 0, 1);
```

Changing the width does not make `setTranslateX()` superfluous, it's still necessary to make the buttons move off screen, else they are just resized to minimum size.

The code for the animation method is as follows:

```
private void switchModulesBar() {
    // Slides in the modules bar when "Modules"-toggle button is pressed
    if (mainBar.getModulesButton().isSelected()) {
        Animation modulesBarAnimation = new Transition() {
            {
                setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(250));
            }

            @Override
            protected void interpolate(double frac) {
                final double curWidth = 200 * frac;
                modulesBar.setPrefWidth(curWidth);
                modulesBar.setTranslateX(-200 + curWidth);
            }
        };
        modulesBarAnimation.play();
    } else { // Slides out the modules bar 
        Animation modulesBarAnimation = new Transition() {
            {
                setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(250));
            }

            @Override
            protected void interpolate(double frac) {
                final double curWidth = 200 * (1.0 - frac);
                modulesBar.setPrefWidth(curWidth);
                modulesBar.setTranslateX(-200 + curWidth);
            }
        };
        modulesBarAnimation.play();
    }
}
```